# Issue with timed animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create different timed animations that run independently from each other,I found a really well made animation code and I adapted it for my needs. I have created an jsFiddle example to show the creation of the animations inside a list item. The problem I'm having is that if I click on one green timed circle, the other ones stop. I don't know how to instantiate them for each row...

Here is the jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3nv6hm7k/)

Some code:

```
var methods = {
     init: function (options) {
         var state = {
             timer: null,
             timerSeconds: 60,
             callback: function () {},
             timerCurrent: 0,
             showPercentage: false,
             fill: false,
             color: '#CCC'
         };

         state = $.extend(state, options);

         return this.each(function () {
             var $this = $(this);
             var data = $this.data('pietimer');
             if (!data) {
                 $this.addClass('pietimer');
                 $this.css({
                     fontSize: $this.width()
                 });
                 $this.data('pietimer', state);
                 if (state.showPercentage) {
                     $this.find('.percent').show();
                 }
                 if (state.fill) {
                     $this.addClass('fill');
                 }
                 $this.pietimer('start');
             }
         });
     },

     stopWatch: function () {

         var data = $(this).data('pietimer');
         if (data) {
             var seconds = (data.timerFinish - (new Date().getTime())) / 1000;
             if (seconds <= 0) {
                 clearInterval(data.timer);
                 $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', 100);
                 data.callback();
             } else {
                 var percent = 100 - ((seconds / (data.timerSeconds)) * 100);
                 $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', percent);
             }
         }
     },

     drawTimer: function (percent) {

         $this = $(this);
         var data = $this.data('pietimer');
         if (data) {
             $this.html('<div class="percent"></div><div class="slice' + (percent > 50 ? ' gt50"' : '"') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
             var deg = 360 / 100 * percent;
             $this.find('.slice .pie').css({
                 '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                     '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                     '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                     'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
             });
             var secs = (data.timerSeconds) * ((100 - percent) / 100); /*NEW*/
             $this.find('.percent').html(Math.round(secs) + ''); /*Changed*/
             if (data.showPercentage) {
                 $this.find('.percent').show();
             }
             if ($this.hasClass('fill')) {
                 $this.find('.slice .pie').css({
                     backgroundColor: data.color
                 });
             } else {
                 $this.find('.slice .pie').css({
                     borderColor: data.color
                 });
             }
         }
     },

     start: function () {

         var data = $(this).data('pietimer');
         if (data) {
             data.timerFinish = new Date().getTime() + (data.timerSeconds * 1000);
             $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', 0);
             data.timer = setInterval("$this.pietimer('stopWatch')", 50);
         }
     },

     reset: function () {
         console.log("flag 4");
         var data = $(this).data('pietimer');
         if (data) {
             clearInterval(data.timer);
             $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', 0);
         }
     }
 };

 $.fn.pietimer = function (method) {

     if (methods[method]) {
         return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
     } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
         return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
     } else {
         $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pietimer');
     }
 };



 function runTimer() {

     $('.timer').pietimer({
         timerSeconds: 60,
         color: '#ccc',
         fill: '#ccc',
         showPercentage: true,
         callback: function () {
             console.log("flag 7");
             // alert("yahoo, timer is done!");
             $('.timer').pietimer('reset');
             $this.find('.percent').html(0);
         }
     });
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to be rude, but you wrote the (relatively) complex jQuery plugin, but you don't know how to run your own(!) plugin on a single element, instead of all elements? In any case, your biggest problem is not in the code you posted, but in `appendToList`.

Comment: Sorry, It's an animation code I found and I adapted it to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, It's here for anyone who would want it :)

LINK: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yikeze/1/edit?console,output)